# how to make button to create a new sheet with new date in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a new project for clinic reservation and in this project. I require a button to click to create a new sheet with a new date, which is one day more than the date of the first sheet. I found a code in the internet which create a new sheet with my template but it create the sheet with today date, but what I need is to create sheet with one day more then the original sheet. Can any one please help?

```
Sub Insert_Sheet_Template()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shName As String

    'name of the sheet template
    shName = "template.xltx"

    'Insert sheet template
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sh = Sheets.Add(Type:=Application.TemplatesPath & shName, _
                            after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    'Give the sheet a name, today's date in this example
    On Error Resume Next
    sh.Name = Format(Date, "yyyy-mmm-dd")
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Change the name of Sheet : " & sh.Name & " manually"
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: Date + 1; it should work.

Comment: Where would one find the "original date" on the "original sheet"?

Comment: i tried date +1 but it only work for one more day but i want to add one day each time i click the button

Comment: i mean what i need is a function to name each new sheet depending on the date of the active sheet like this but i dont know how to write it 
sh.Name = Format(Date + activesheet Date, "yyyy-mmm-dd")
please tell me the write formula

Comment: i need to write a command to name the new sheet with a date +1 to the date of the current sheet